# React Native: Uncaught Error undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeImagePicker.default.showImagePicker')

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image-picker

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.instamobile.io/mobile-development/react-native-firebase-storage/) to create an image upload app using Firebase and got to the very end and when I build the app using `npx react-native run-ios` I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error 
undefined is not an object (evaluating
'_reactNativeImagePicker.default.showImagePicker')

Source

 29 |  }
 30 |};
>31 |ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, respon
    |^
 32 |  if (response.didCancel) {
 33 |    console.log('User cancelled image picked
 34 |  } else if (response.error) {

UploadScreen.js (31:5)
```

This is my UploadScreen.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

export default function UploadScreen() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0);

  const selectImage = () => {
    const options = {
      maxWidth: 2000,
      maxHeight: 2000,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images'
      }
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };
        console.log(source);
        setImage(source);
      }
    });
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const { uri } = image;
    const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
    setUploading(true);
    setTransferred(0);
    const task = storage()
      .ref(filename)
      .putFile(uploadUri);
    // set progress state
    task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
      setTransferred(
        Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
      );
    });
    try {
      await task;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    setUploading(false);
    Alert.alert(
      'Photo uploaded!',
      'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
    );
    setImage(null);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.selectButton} onPress={selectImage}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Pick an image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        {image !== null ? (
          <Image source={{ uri: image.uri }} style={styles.imageBox} />
        ) : null}
        {uploading ? (
          <View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
            <Progress.Bar progress={transferred} width={300} />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.uploadButton} onPress={uploadImage}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload image</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#bbded6'
  },
  selectButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  uploadButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ffb6b9',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 50,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  progressBarContainer: {
    marginTop: 20
  },
  imageBox: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

I believe I read that the `showImagePicker` is no longer in use by the react-native-image-picker package so I think this may be the problem here?

If that is correct then I assume there is a replacement for 'showImagePicker', if so what is it and how can I modify my code to work?

Thank you :)

Edit: I have now implemented launchCamera and launchImageLibrary which allows me to pick a photo from the library but then I get this warning/error? and nothing is uploaded to Firebase.... [image: Console Warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import changed in v4, in the tutorial the version is v3 or lesser. `yarn add` or `npm install` will always install the latest stable release so you need to check for breaking changes if there is a change in the major version.

https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#methods

There are the new imports

```
import {launchCamera, launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
```

Check this reference of import & export change https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1746#issuecomment-858670659

From the repo readme

> Make sure you're reading the doc applicable to your version, for
> example if your using version 3.8.0 go to tag 3.8.0 and read those
> docs. This doc is always that of main branch.
>
> Also read version release notes for any breaking changes especially if
> you're updating the major version.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to find these new imports etc and implement them but now I get a new error, I described it in an edit on my post.

Comment: You need to add a catch block with your promise to get the exact error.